# How can I construct regex to check valid path?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to construct regular expression for the bellow path.Can you help me to construct regex for it?

```
path  = "root-dir/document/2018/02/29/14/02-sample.txt"
pattern = '((a-z)+(-)(a-z)+/(a-z)+/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{2)(-)(a-z)+(.)(a-z)+)'
bool(re.match(pattern,path))

"root-dir/document/2015/01/25/13/01-sample.txt" //this should be accepted
"root-dir/2015/01/25/13/01-sample.txt" //this should not be accepted
"root-dir/document/201/01/25/13/01-sample.txt" //this should not be accepted as 201 part should be 4 digit
"root-dir/document/2015/01/2/13/01-sample.txt" //this should be not accepted as 2 part should be 2 digit
"root-dir/document/2015/01/25/13/sample.txt" //this should not be accepted as the last part should be something like this 03-sample.txt
```

Comment: What are the variations possible in path and which one you would want to match and which ones you want to reject?

Comment: Seems you are wanting to get separate path between '/'?

Comment: Provide some examples of paths you want to reject.

Comment: You should add context, and more examples of what is accepted and what not.

Comment: Instead of using regexes for that, Python 3's [```pathlib```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) standard module is a better and the recommended option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few problems with your pattern, correct usage is:

```
import re
pattern = r'([a-z]+(-)[a-z]+/[a-z]+/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})(-)[a-z]+(\.)[a-z]+)'
print(bool(re.match(pattern,path))) #True
```

Your pattern `'((a-z)+(-)(a-z)+/(a-z)+/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{2)(-)(a-z)+(.)(a-z)+)'` do not work because:

- `\d{2)` - you should close `{` with `}` not `)`
- `a-z` - this is equivalent to any lowercase letter inside and only inside `[` `]` not `(` `)`
- `.` - you should use `\.` if you mean character `.` (ASCII: 46) as in `re` it means any character which is not newline, also remember to use raw-string rather than common string

Answer (score -1):

If you only need to see if that path is valid in the sense that you want to know if it exists, then just use:

```
import os

os.path.exists(path) # return true if the path exists
```